# Pythagorean Triple parametrization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For the pythagorean tripple (x,y,z) such that $x^{2} + y^{2} = z^{2}$ , we know that $x,y,z$ can't be all odd, which means either x,y or z must be even.
We can choose y even to get many parametrizations with y even ($a^2 - b^2 , 2ab , a^2 + b+2$ ) , or we can choose x even to get many parametrizations with x even ($2ab , a^2 - b^2, a^2 + b^2$).

That's because if we make y=2ab  then we have that
$ y^2 = (2a²)(2b²) = z^2 - x^2 = (x+z)(x-z) $
So from that we get $2a² = x+z$  and  $2b² = x-z   $
then we have $y=2ab , x = a^2 - b^2$  and  $z = a^2 + b^2$

Now, I'm interested in the case where we choose z = 2ab,  to get many parametrizations with z even ( particularly the ones where either x,y are both even or both odd ).

But i don't know how to get that parametrization :
$z = 2ab$ ..., then i don't know what else to do.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you can read Spanish, perhaps you find this article useful: http://axiomaeleccion.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/ternas-pitagoricas-i.html

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go through *primitive* [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) first, that is, those Pythagorean triples $(x, y, z)$ where $x, y$ are coprime. One can easily show that any Pythagorean triple can be obtained from a suitable primitive Pythagorean  one $(x, y, z)$ in the form $ (tx, ty, tz)$, for some $t$.

For the primitive Pythagorean triples, you can easily show that $x, y$ have distinct parity, that is, one of them is odd and the other is even, so $z$ is odd.